# Exibir informação do banco de dados com segurança

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, segurança, criptografia

Que tipo de criptografia eu devo usar para criptografar um CPF no banco de dados e depois mostrar esse mesmo CPF (descriptografado) para o cliente de maneira segura?

Comment: Esses CPFs são usados para associar as pessoas a informações sensíveis (por exemplo, financeiras)? À primeira vista, me parece um pouco exagerado querer criptografar um CPF.

Comment: Infelizmente eu preciso criptografar o CPF e outras informações amigo.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Segurança é um assunto complexo, não basta escolher um "tipo de criptografia" e tudo ficará seguro. Existem diversas formas de usar o mesmo recurso e ser seguro ou não.

Talvez você queira usar a [criptografia do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html) se for este banco de dados que está usando. Eu não saberia dizer qual é melhor para o seu caso. Eu poderia chutar que `AES_ENCRYPT()` é uma boa. Não sei se teria vantagens se fazer o trabalho da criptografia pelo PHP.

Se ainda quiser usar o PHP, pode estudar o [`mcrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php). É algo complexo e tem diversas opções. Ninguém poderá dizer qual é a correta para você.

Claro que mostrar para o "cliente" de maneira segura envolve um outro problema. A conexão precisa ser segura. Não adianta mandar esta informação descriptografada. Normalmente se faz uso do protocolo HTTPS usando a criptografia provida pelo SSL/TLS que fica transparente para sua aplicação.

Mas ainda pode haver um problema no curto período em que o dado está *descriptografado* em seu servidor. Normalmente isto não é considerado um grande problema porque se seu servidor está vulnerável para que alguém tenha acesso, o problema é outro e é maior.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas amigo. vou estudar um pouco e qualquer dúvida eu volto aq.

Comment: Tanto `AES_ENCRYPT` quanto `mcrypt` parecem boas opções, o difícil é usá-las de forma apropriada. Criptografar no próprio banco (opção 1) protege os dados contra o cenário em que o conteúdo do banco foi comprometido (um disco de backup descartado de forma incorreta, for exemplo) e *talvez* ajude um pouco contra um SQL Injection (se o atacante não sabe a chave, ele não pode injetar um comando `AES_DECRYPT` arbitrário - mais *ainda* pode mudar uma ou outra condição de busca de modo a enganar o servidor fazendo-o decifrar mais do que devia). A opção 2 faz o mesmo, e um tantinho melhor(continua..)

Comment: O problema é onde a chave está guardada. Se ela estiver num arquivo de configurações protegido por restrições de acesso (o mais comum), então um atacante com controle do servidor poderia recuperá-la. Se a chave só existe em memória é mais difícil, mas é inconveniente ter que entrar com uma senha a cada *reboot*. Esses são cenários cada vez menos improváveis, mas é bom ter isso em mente ao planejar uma solução. Segurança é um tópico muito contextual, como bem apontado no início da resposta: "Existem diversas formas de usar o mesmo recurso e ser seguro ou não".